# How to disable datatables default sorting?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am fetching records from Database and displaying in table. And for search i used datatables. but i want to disable default sorting of datatables. So  i tried to disable sorting by using following code

```
    $('#offer_table').dataTable({
         "aaSorting": []
  });
```

its working perfectly , but the issue is , its shows some alert

[image: you cannot reinitialize datatable]

How to fix this problem ? May be this question is silly but sorry i tried in google to fix this issue but i cant able to fix. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code or error messages.  It makes it hard for people to search for it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen due to some reasons, but usually because you tried to initialize twice or set the properties after initialize.

Check this [link](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3) for more info about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just to add to douglasf89's answer, you are probably trying to initialize the Datatable twice.  If you must do this, it is first necessary to call

```
yourTable.destroy();
```

between intitializations.

Thus, the code below is valid:

```
function createTable() {
  yourTable = $('#offer_table').dataTable({
     "aaSorting": []
  });
}
createTable();
yourTable.destroy();
createTable();
```

Still, this [link](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3) answers your question more thoroughly.

While your problem may not be caused by aaSorting, there are alternate syntaxes to accomplish this. Legacy Datatables doc - ([legacy.datatables.net/ref](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref)), you may substitute aaSorting with

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "bSort": false
} );
```

to disable sorting on a specific column, use

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
] } );
```

to change the default column to sort by, use

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

// Sort immediately with columns 0 and 1
oTable.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'], [1,'asc'] ] );
```